# Integrate automation tests with TestRail

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, testrail

i'm trying to integrate my automation tests with TestRail. I work with c#, ef and NUnit

I have test, with his Id in TestRail. In the description, I indicated the Id of the case from TestRail

```
[Test(Description = "C596")]
[TestCase()]
[TestCase()]
```

OneTimeSetUp

```
public void OneTimeSetUp(){
Client = new TestRailClient(Url, User, Password);
var commandResult = Client.AddRun(_projectId, 2, "test run demo" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, "test run demo", 2);
}
```

**My problem**: i can't test case Id in TearDown for check test case result

In TearDown I tried to get test case id with this way

`var id = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Id`
this method returns the wrong id, which i don't need

next I found this example, but I could not understand how it works

```
var id = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Description").ToString().Replace("C","");
```

All my TearDown:

```
public void Dispose()
        {
            var id = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.ID;
            var result = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            var testRailStatus = result switch
            {
                TestStatus.Failed => ResultStatus.Failed,
                TestStatus.Passed => ResultStatus.Passed,
                _ => ResultStatus.Retest
            };

            var resultForCase = Client.AddResultForCase(_runId, ulong.Parse(id), testRailStatus);
            Console.WriteLine(resultForCase.WasSuccessful);
        }
```

How I can get test case Id for check his result? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using TestCase attributes, the Description property must be specified inside each TestCase attribute.

```
[TestCase(Description = "C596")]
[TestCase(Description = "C596")]
```

Now to get id, you can use your code:

`var id = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Description").ToString().Replace("C","");`